# Android Won't Display A Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I recently discovered that since my app is pulling so much data from a few URLs, it takes about 3-7 seconds for it to load the main layout.  So, I made a layout called 'loading' to display, which is just simply a TextView that states "Please wait while data is being collected...".  However, when I run my app, it won't display the 'loading' layout.  It simply goes black for a while, like it used to before, and then go to the main layout.  I tried cleaning the project too, and it still does this.  Here's a portion of my Main.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    populateArray();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set up click listeners for all buttons
    View v1 = findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
    v1.setOnClickListener(this);

    View v2 = findViewById(R.id.colorCheck);
    v2.setOnClickListener(this);

    View v3 = findViewById(R.id.terms);
    v3.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

`populateArray();` is the method that is pulling all the information of the internet.  So, I figured, "Why not tell it to set the content view immediately to 'loading', have it run `populateArray();`, then display the main layout?"  Obviously, I must be missing something here.  Any ideas?

==========================================================================

EDIT:  I tried using AsyncTask, but I'm getting a force close.  I'm also getting a warning saying the AsyncTask class is never used.  Here's my code:

P.S. `ProgressDialog dialog;` is a global definition.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                "Please wait while data is collected...", true);

        // Set up click listeners for all buttons
        View v1 = findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
        v1.setOnClickListener(this);

        View v2 = findViewById(R.id.colorCheck);
        v2.setOnClickListener(this);

        View v3 = findViewById(R.id.terms);
        v3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

And...

```
    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask <String[][], String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String[][]... voidThisArray) {
            String voidThisString = null;
            populateArray();
            return voidThisString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String voidThisString) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

I would give you the LogCat for the force close but for some reason the LogCat isn't displaying anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [an AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to first: create a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) that will display the loading message. Then the `AsyncTask` will work in the background collecting all of the data.

Hope that helps.

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dia;

    @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
        dia = new ProgressDialog(MyContext.this);
        dia.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dia.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
        dia.setCancelable(false);
        dia.show();

                // Set up preserver download stuff
        }

    @Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // perform server download stuff
    }

    @Override public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {
        if (prog == null)
            return;
        dia.setProgress(prog[0]);
    }

    @Override  protected void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
        // Do any post op stuff
        dia.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used AsyncTask before, but only once.  What should I put in each of the doInBackground, onPostExecute, and any other needed methods?  Also, what should go in the onCreate method; the ProgressDialog?

Comment: No, well, it's up to you. I create the `ProgressDialog` in the `onPreExecute()` method. That's also where I set up all of the necessary items that will be needed for downloading. Then in `doInBackground()` is where you would handle the downloading and from there you return your progress for the `onProgressUpdate`. Finally in `onPostExcecute` you clean up all of the widgets and socket stuffs and kill the `ProgressDialog`. You create an `AsyncTask` in `onCreate` and start it there as well.

Comment: I'm a little lost - but, I posted what I do have at the bottom of my question.  Sorry, I'm still pretty new to this.

Comment: Awesome! Only a few more questions. The error I'm getting from your code is from "MyContext" being undefined. Where should I define it and what should I set it equal to? Secondly, where do I put `setContentView(main)`; - in `onPostExecute()`? Lastly, how should I set up my `onCreate` method? Sorry for being such a pest!

Comment: MyContext.this is a place holder for a context you supply. I nest my `AsyncTask`s in my activities. This will allow me to just straight reference them [so I can use them as a context]. You would place your `setContentView(int)` in `onCreate(Bundle)` as normal. Your `onCreate(Bundle)` method will also be as normal, just with a `new Task().execute();` line in it.

Comment: MyContext.this is the name of your specific activity (MyActivityName.this). You shouldn't use the setContent in your onPostExecute because this will still cause a delay. You should UPDATE your layout after the onPostExecute finishes. So setContent should go in your main activity onCreate, and also in onCreate you have to actually call your AsyncTask new Task().execute() I think it is.

Comment: Awesome! It worked!  Thank you AedonEtLIRE and Jack!  Only one more minor problem - the progress bar stays at 0% - it never updates.  Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, you just call `MyAsyncTask.publishProgress(T... vals)`

Comment: You call `MyAsyncTask.publishProgress(T... vals)` from `doInBackground()`. `T` is just the type of the second generic of the class. `<Void, Integer, Void>` in `extend AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>` are generics. So `T` in `MyAsyncTask.publishProgress(T... vals)` should be `MyAsyncTask.publishProgress(Integer... vals)` in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

You should see [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) page for information about threading. Basically if your application is going to do any long running operation, you want it in a thread. Your UI is locking up because your performing this operation on your UI thread.

As far as progress updates, I personally use a ProgressDialog to show when something is happening, although you could build a custom view to indicate this.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and execute

```
populateArray();
```

in doInBackground method of AsyncTask.

And call

```
setContentView
```

only once you can show loading by using onPreExecute and onPostExecute method of AsyncTask